# Install homebrew on mac m1 freeze at receiving objects

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am trying to install homebrew on the M1 mac using following command line.

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

However, the process always stuck at 4% of receiving object step as below:

```
......
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod go-w /opt/homebrew/share/zsh /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown wen.yan /opt/homebrew/bin /opt/homebrew/etc /opt/homebrew/include /opt/homebrew/lib /opt/homebrew/sbin /opt/homebrew/share /opt/homebrew/var /opt/homebrew/opt /opt/homebrew/share/zsh /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew/linked /opt/homebrew/Cellar /opt/homebrew/Caskroom /opt/homebrew/Frameworks
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/chgrp admin /opt/homebrew/bin /opt/homebrew/etc /opt/homebrew/include /opt/homebrew/lib /opt/homebrew/sbin /opt/homebrew/share /opt/homebrew/var /opt/homebrew/opt /opt/homebrew/share/zsh /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew/linked /opt/homebrew/Cellar /opt/homebrew/Caskroom /opt/homebrew/Frameworks
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R wen.yan:admin /opt/homebrew
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
remote: Enumerating objects: 220323, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (47/47), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (47/47), done.
Receiving objects:   4% (8813/220323), 3.78 MiB | 1.79 MiB/s
```

I did have `command line tool xcode` installed and I rebooted my machine a couple of times, but no luck so far. Any ideas?

Comment: How long did you wait? FWIW, Github was having issues earlier today, perhaps related.

Comment: @robertklep, I started to try since yesterday. And there were 2 times, I wait for about half hour. It always freeze at 4% every single time, even the speed was NOT changing.

Comment: What does `env GIT_TRACE=2 git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/brew homebrew` show? It seems to be stuck on that part of the installation process.

Comment: @robertklep, it shows some trace lines (no error from what I see) and then stuck at that 4% of receiving objects step again.

Comment: It sounds like a local issue, I cannot reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the MacAfee installed by our IT team. Once disable it, homebrew was installed successfully.

Comment: That is good to know, worth sharing it into twitter :D